# add taxa manually to phylogenetic tree in R

Tags: r, phylogeny

I have a phylogenetic tree in R and currently the variables are the taxa_names. I want to assign taxa_names from a data.frame (the tree is based on said data.frame).

```
 matrix <- data.frame(row.names = c('aa','bb','cc'),aa=c(0,1,1),bb=c(1,1,0),cc=c(0,1,1))
> matrix
   aa bb cc
aa  0  1  0
bb  1  1  1
cc  1  0  1

d.matrix <- dist(matrix)
h.matrix <- hclust(d.matrix) %>% ape::as.phylo(.)
```

The taxa names are `aa,bb,cc`. But I want to set the taxa_names to `t` and `a`. These letters are from the data.frame `dd`.

```
dd <- data.frame(row.names = c('aa','bb','cc'),values = c('t','a','a'))
> dd
   values
aa      t
bb      a
cc      a
```

`dd` actually has a lot more columns but I cut it short here.

How to manually set taxa_names for a tree in R? The desired taxa_names are specyfied in a data.frame

EDIT: I tried `taxa_names <- c()` and `AssignTaxonomy()` (from `dada2` package) without success

Comment: Do you want to rename the columns of your matrix, modify its row names, or add the taxa names as an additional column, or something else?  Please provide your desired output.  Also should "data.frame `d`" be "data.frame `dd`"?  Are you using a specific package?  I'm guessing `AssignTaxonomy()` is not part of base R...

Comment: @Limey I edited my post...

Answer (score 0):

First, I find it's good practice to read your data as `character` instead of `factor` (the default for data.frames). This can be done by using the `stringsAsFactors` argument:

```
dd <- data.frame(row.names = c('aa','bb','cc'),values = c('t','a','a'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then you can just assign the name directly to the specific entry of the `phylo` object (you can reorder as you want it):

```
h.matrix$tip.label = dd$values
```

To know more about the `phylo` class check https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ape/versions/2.6-3/topics/read.tree